# Ruby include? many

Tags: ruby

```
[26] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4].any?{|x| [2,5].include?(x)}
=> true

[27] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4].include?(2,5)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(2 for 1)
from (pry):27:in `include?'

[29] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4].include?(2 || 5) # I want this behavior...
=> true

[30] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4].include?(5 || 2) # but that only works because the above expression evaluates to 2... this to 5
=> false
```

Is there a shortcut of some sort to see if an array has any of several things in it? `.include` lets me test the array against a single value... I can't seem to come up with a clever way to check against multiple, other than my original `.any?` at the top there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the intersection and see if there are any in the resulting array

```
2.1.1 :013 > ([1,2,3,4] & [1,2]).any?
 => true
2.1.1 :014 > ([1,2,3,4] & [5,6]).any?
 => false
2.1.1 :015 > ([1,2,3,4] & [1,6]).any?
 => true
```

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,5]
(a & b) == b #=> false, will check if all items of b are contained in a
(a & b).any? #=> true, will check if any item of b is contained in a
```

PS: `2 || 5` is equal to `2` and `5 || 2` is the same as `5`.

Comment: I forgot about the `&` for arrays!! thanks!! the `.any` is what I had in my head, but couldn't get the syntax right.